# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred

Tags: c#, tesseract

I use VS 2012 to do this tesseract code project.

I created WPF(C# project) import tesseractengine3.dll set using tesseract;

and created variable:

```
TesseractProcessor test = new TesseractProcessor() ;
```

and then compile the code in debug mode (x86 , with target .net 4)

It shows Error message dialog

**"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll**

Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Recog.OcrTest' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."

I searched on tesseractdotnet blog, and also google a lot of website and found nothing.

PS. I can run this code succesfully on VS2008. But when I code in VS2012 is occured error.

I cannot do my project in VS2008 because I have to some code of kinect which cannot work with VS2008.

Please anyone guide my how to solve this problem. I stuck with this problem for 1 week.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582374/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-windows-markup-xamlparseexception-occurr?rq=1

Comment: Is the DLL you are using built for .NET 4.0 or are you using a .NET 2.0 version hoping it will work with .NET 4.0?

Comment: Before anything: is this exception caught and handled within the dll? I'm asking this because if you configure Visual Studio, it'll break in any exception you turn on in Debug/Exceptions... at the time of the throw regardless if it is handled later or not. I've seen many 3rd party libraries which had exception within them, but they handled it also, it didn't bubble up to the software.

Comment: I use tesseractengine3 wrapper r590 , so it is compatible on .net 2.0 4.0 and 4.5


And for now it shows this error message when I run it

"First-chance exception at 0x7603c6e3 (KernelBase.dll) in ProjectTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x002dc314."